# The OAuth class could not be found! Did you install and enable the oauth extension?

Tags: php, oauth

i am experiencing this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox_Exception?' with message 'The
>   OAuth class could not be found! Did you install and enable the oauth
>   extension?' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ITamAppServer\dropbox-php-master\src\Dropbox\OAuth\PHP.php:36
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\path\to\file\sample2.php(12):
>   Dropbox_OAuth_PHP->construct('xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx') #1 {main}
>   thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ITamAppServer\dropbox-php-master\src\Dropbox\OAuth\PHP.php
>   on line

i've already downloaded the extension for oauth and included it in php.ini, but still the extension cannot be found.

Comment: do you see oauth in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: theres no oauth in phpinfo(), i was also expecting to see the oauth after I put "extension=php_oauth.dll" on php.ini

Comment: I also restarted apache, there's still no oauth on phpinfo()